# Is fundamental group of a finite volume, negatively curved, cusped manifold a non-uniform lattice?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, topological-groups, lattices

$\DeclareMathOperator\Mob{Mob}$**Some background:** (1) A Riemannian manifold $M$ is pinched negatively curved if there is a constant $\tau<\kappa<0$  such that all the sectional curvatures are Between $\tau$ and $\kappa$. When $M$ is compact, it is a consequence of the condition that $M$ is negatively curved.

(2) A lattice of a locally compact, second countable group $H$ is a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ such that $H/\Gamma$ has finite Haar volume. $\Gamma$ is call cocompact or uniform if $H/\Gamma$ is compact, non-uniform otherwise.

(3) For a compact metric space $(X,d)$ without isolated points. Define the cross-ratio on a quadruple of distinct points in $X$ as:
$$\mathbb{B}(x,y,x',y')=\frac{d(x,x')d(y,y')}{d(x,y')d(y,x')}.$$
A homeomorphism of $X$ is called Möbius if it preserves the cross-ratio. And denote $\Mob(X)$ be the group of all Möbius homeomorphisms of $X$. $\Mob(X)$ is locally compact, see

> B. Nica, Proper isometric actions of hyperbolic groups on Lp-spaces, Compositio Mathematica
> 149 (2013), no. 5, 773–792.

**The question:** Let $M$ be a pinched negatively curved, finite volume, cusped manifold, and $\Gamma$ its fundamental group. Considering the boundary $X$ of the universal cover of $M$ with the visual metric, it is true that $\Gamma$ is a lattice of the Möbius group $\Mob(X)$ of $X$. If $\Mob(X)$ is not discrete, is it true that $\Gamma$ is a non-uniform lattice of $\Mob(X)$?

**Remark:** 1. The answer is yes if one of the cuspidal groups is (virtually) not abelian but nilpotent.

2. This is a consequence of Hilbert-Smith conjecture. Therefore I believe the answer is yes.
3. One way to show this is to construct a 'hyperbolic element' in $\Mob(X)$ with one fixed point as a cusp point of the manifold.

Comment: Could you add more background, namely, the definitions of "strictly negatively curved", "Mob(X)" and "non-uniform lattice"?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks; I edit the question for more backgrounds.

Comment: Could you also explain (or give a reference to) why $Mob(X)$ is locally compact? Also what is a "cusp point" or cusp groups? With your definition $\Gamma$ need not be relatively hyperbolic so the notion of cusp might not make sense.

Comment: If a convergence group fixes a point at infinity, then it cannot contain both hyperbolic and parabolic elements. See e.g. Bowditch Convergence groups and configuration spaces, lemma 2.2. So your item 3 is impossible for the standard notion of cusp (defined if your $\Gamma$ is relatively hyperbolic).

Comment: @IgorBelegradek. I may misunderstand it. The cusped manifolds here are noncompact complete, negatively curved manifolds with finite Riemannian volume and without boundary. I abused the term here; the standard definition of cusped manifolds is for hyperbolic manifolds only. I think it is enough to assure the relative hyperbolicity of $\Gamma$. the fact $Mob(X)$ is locally compact appears in a paper a B. Nica, I ass a reference there.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek The problem is that we assume $Mob(X)$ is not discrete. Think about $PSL_2(\mathbb R)$ acts on the circle. There is no hyperbolic element in $\Gamma$. But in $Mob(X)$, I do not have an answer. Another point, $Mob(X)$ is not a convergence group, discreteness is the key.

Comment: It is an interesting question. The notion of a cusp will make sense e.g. if the curvature is bounded between two negative constants, but not in your generality.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks. I may change it to a pinched curved case.